# insert records with request.form gives me JET error 80040e14

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I am trying to insert record using `for each request.form`

And output is:

> "INSERT INTO invdat (dispid,disdate,custid) VALUES ('2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9',('3/13/2011, 3/13/2011, 3/13/2011, 3/13/2011, 3/14/2011, 3/14/2011','')
>
>
> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14'
>
> Syntax error (comma) in query expression '('3/13/2011, 3/13/2011, 3/13/2011, 3/13/2011, 3/14/2011, 3/14/2011','')'. "

Please help

Comment: classic asp? or .net? Show your code and give more detail on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Classic ASP
"<%

If Request.Form("Submitted") = "Yes" Then
'Start Loop
For Each item In Request.Form
'Run Insert Code
sql="INSERT INTO invoicedetails (dispid,disdate,custid)"
sql=sql & " VALUES "
sql=sql & "('" & Request.Form("dipatchid") & "',"
sql=sql & "('" & Request.Form("dispatchdate") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("custid") & "')"

'execute the insert to SQL Server
Set MM_editCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection = MM_MY_STRING
MM_editCmd.CommandText = sql
Response.Write(sql)
MM_editCmd.Execute
MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection.Close
Next
End If

%>"

Comment: Edit your question and update it with your code.

Answer (score 1):

"INSERT INTO invdat (dispid,disdate,custid) VALUES ('2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9',('3/13/2011, 3/13/2011, 3/13/2011, 3/13/2011, 3/14/2011, 3/14/2011','') **)"**

You might have left out the closing bracket, so it was off balance?

Comment: nop, the prob. is some where in values... I am fetching values by using 'for each request.form' method , and I have multiple rows in form. that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`"INSERT INTO invdat (dispid,disdate,custid) VALUES ('2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9','3/13/2011, 3/13/2011, 3/13/2011, 3/13/2011, 3/14/2011, 3/14/2011','')`"

Try this. You can not use `( within values(....)`